# Error CS1002 At Run Time - Markdown Parser (Headers Only)

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax

"src/Solution.cs(9,12): error CS1002: ; expected"

I cannot work out why I am being shown this error? I have put my code below. I am very inexperienced at c-sharp, I normally work in c++, so maybe a small syntax error somewhere?

```
public class Challenge
{
  public static string MarkdownParser( string markdown )
  {
    
        string inputText = markdown;
        string outputText;
        
        unsigned int indexOfFirstSpace = 0;
        unsigned int inputTextLength = 0;
        
        //Trim Spaces Before & After String
        inputText = inputText.Trim();
    
        if (inputText.StartsWith("#")){
        
        //Find Index oF First Space & Store
        indexOfFirstSpace = inputText.IndexOf(" ");
          
        if (indexOfFirstSpace > 6){
          return inputText;
        }
          
        else{
        
        //Find Length Of Input String
        inputTextLength = inputText.Length;
        
        //Store Hashes In Own String
        string hashes = inputText.Substring(0, indexOfFirstSpace);
        
        //Store header text in string
        string headerText = inputText.Substring(indexOfFirstSpace,(inputTextLength - indexOfFirstSpace));
    
        //Trim Spaces From Front
        headerText = headerText.TrimStart();
        
        //Build Output
        outputText = "<h" + indexOfFirstSpace + ">" + headerText + "</h" + indexOfFirstSpace + ">";
        
        return outputText;
        }
    }
    
          else {
            return inputText;
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: The _unsigned int_  in C# is called _uint_

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You tried to use 'unsigned int'. in C# the keyword for that is uinit.
2. The returned type for inputText.Length is actually an int, so the fixed code should be:

   public class Challenge
   {
   public static string MarkdownParser(string markdown)
   {

   ```
        string inputText = markdown;
        string outputText;

        //  ---- Changed these variables to Int ----
        int indexOfFirstSpace = 0;
        int inputTextLength = 0;

        //Trim Spaces Before & After String
        inputText = inputText.Trim();

        if (inputText.StartsWith("#"))
        {

            //Find Index oF First Space & Store
            indexOfFirstSpace = inputText.IndexOf(" ");

            if (indexOfFirstSpace > 6)
            {
                return inputText;
            }

            else
            {

                //Find Length Of Input String
                inputTextLength = inputText.Length;

                //Store Hashes In Own String
                string hashes = inputText.Substring(0, indexOfFirstSpace);

                //Store header text in string
                string headerText = inputText.Substring(indexOfFirstSpace, (inputTextLength - indexOfFirstSpace));

                //Trim Spaces From Front
                headerText = headerText.TrimStart();

                //Build Output
                outputText = "<h" + indexOfFirstSpace + ">" + headerText + "</h" + indexOfFirstSpace + ">";

                return outputText;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return inputText;
        }
    }
   ```

   }